# FCM formatting issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I'm sending to Firebase Cloud Messaging with the following:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=[SERVER_KEY] (The one found in Firebase Project>Settings>Cloud Messaging

Body:
{
    "notification" = {
        "title": "Title",
        "text": "Your Text",
        "sound": "default",
        "badge": "1"
     },
    "to" = "a4fbc860-23fd-4ffc-95b7-11c90d8db320" (The Device ID from the hand held)
}
```

When I send this I continually receive: {"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing. The docs aren't very clear on what elements are required and the nomenclature is different between the error messages and the Firebase site.  I've tried to swap out "registration_ids" with "to" (using the array, of course), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending to a single device, "to" field should specify an FCM registration token, not a Device ID. You can retrieve the registration token using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` method.

This token looks like two strings, a short and a long one, separated by a colon, e.g. `"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."`

Links to relevant documentation:

- [Registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register)
- [Legacy HTTP Protocol errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)